# trying to add a new jquery validator method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to add a validator rule which will work like:

> When we apply this rule on an element then it should only be validated
>   on the non-empty values of the elements which we passed through params.
>   Means, it must validate itself if and only if one of the passed
>   elements have non-empty value.

the rule what I am trying:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("reqAfter",function(a,b,c){
    for(var i in c){
        var $d=$(c[i]);
        return !($d.length&&$d.val()!==""&&a=="");
    }
},"Please provide some value!");
```

like:

```
rules: {
    sField: { reqAfter: ['#startD', '#endD'] },
    startD: { regex: /^(\d{4,4})-(\d{2,2})-(\d{2,2})$/, reqAfter: ['#sField'] },
    endD: { regex: /^(\d{4,4})-(\d{2,2})-(\d{2,2})$/, reqAfter: ['#sField', '#startD'] }
}
```

for this form:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I sort it by myself.

Working validator method is:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("reqAfter", function (e, b, a) {
    if (!a || a.length < 1) return !0;
    else {
        var b = !1,
            c;
        for (c in a) {
            var d = $(a[c]);
            if (d.length && d.val() !== "") {
                b = e === "" ? !0 : !1;
                break
            }
        }
        return !b
    }
}, "Please provide some value!");
```

Thanks to me...